# Build Integration Services project with MSBUILD

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

Is it possible to build the solution (to get the .ispac file) of an Integration Services Project using msbuild.exe?

I get different errors, e.g.

```
error MSB4067: The element <DeploymentModel> beneath element <Proj
ect> is unrecognized.
```

Is msbuild also for SSIS projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft released standalone tools to build and deploy specifically to be used in devops pipelines but can be used anywhere

Please see the official documentation on [Standalone SQL Server Integration Service (SSIS) DevOps Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/devops/ssis-devops-standalone?view=sql-server-ver15)

After installing it you can call it like below to build

```
SSISBuild.exe -p:"D:\SSISProjectPath\MyHelloWorld\MyHelloWorld.dtproj" -o:"D:\MySpecialOutputFolder\ssis\build"
```

And then deploy it

```
SSISDeploy.exe -s:D:\MySpecialOutputFolder\ssis\build\MyHelloWorld.ispac -d:catalog;/SSISDB/destfolder;myssisserver -at:win
```